# Element is not hiding in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The h5 i want to hide when there is no childrent in the ul element. The delete id element works as when i click on it, it fade in an image inside li element which has class cross. When the image is clicked it removes itself and it's previous sibling. The close-delete element when click hides the
cross image. I want it to when there is no children in the ul element both delete id element and close-delete id element to hide. But not working
This is the html.

```
        <h5 id="delete">Delete</h5>
        <h5 id="close-delete">hide</h5>
        <ul id="list-div">
            <li class="links"><a href="https://www.youtube.com" id="urlls"><div class="spann">youtube</div></a></li>
            <li class="cross"><img src="images/x-button.png" class="cross"></li>
            <li class="links"><a href="https://www.youtube.com" id="urlls"><div class="spann">heroku</div></a></li>
            <li class="cross"><img src="images/x-button.png" class="cross"></li>
        </ul>
```

javascript.

```
if($("#list-div").children().length() == 0){
    $("#delete").hide();
    $("#close-delete").hide();
}
```

Comment: But list-div has children right here?

Answer (score 3):

For the code to work two things should be done:

Length should be called as `length` not `length()`

Second thing is that Your condition is wrong. In HTML Your div has children, but You are checking if it is empty. So double check Your condition here `$("#list-div").children().length == 0`.

Working example:

```
if($("#list-div").children().length !== 0){
    $("#delete").hide();
    $("#close-delete").hide();
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/he0921Lz/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `.length()` is not a method, but a property so you don't need `()`

This should work.

```js
if ($("#list-div").children.length == 0) {
  $("#delete").hide();
  $("#close-delete").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5 id="delete">Delete</h5>
<h5 id="close-delete">hide</h5>
<ul id="list-div">
  <li class="links">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com" id="urlls">
      <div class="spann">youtube</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="cross"><img src="images/x-button.png" class="cross"></li>
  <li class="links">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com" id="urlls">
      <div class="spann">heroku</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="cross"><img src="images/x-button.png" class="cross"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is not true. https://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: @Unmitigated, Oh. I don't use JQuery. `children` is a vanilla JS thing.

Comment: Your snippet is clearly using jQuery. For example: `$("#list-div").children`. What is `$` here?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
if( $('#list-div li').length === 0){

  $( "#delete" ).hide();
    $("#close-delete").hide();
    
}
```

Code here:

https://jsfiddle.net/HenryXilojHerrera/gy2rzjkp/11/